# What is the formula that is used by three.js to create the pattern that is seen when two overlapping 2-D surfaces are shown in SageMath?

Tags: three.js, sage

I'm trying to understand the pattern (looks similar to an animal print) that shows when two different colored planes are plotted on (almost) the same plane. What is the formula that SageMath uses--using three.js--to create the pattern shown in the graph? The SageMath question/support area sent me to this support section for answers.

Example: Here one plane is slightly larger-- which makes SageMath show them both, but with a pattern. Also, as you move/manipulate the graph with the mouse, the pattern changes. What formula or information does SageMath (three.js) use to show the pattern?

I used the Sage Cell Server online to plot this (below) at https://sagecell.sagemath.org/:

```
M = implicit_plot3d(lambda x,y,z: x, (-15,15), (-15,15), (-15,15), rgbcolor= (0.0, 1.0, 0.0), frame=true) 
N = implicit_plot3d(lambda x,y,z: x, (-15,15), (-15,15), (-15,15.5), rgbcolor= (0.0, 0.0, 1.0), frame=true) 
M+N
```

Thanks for any information you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Sage, but this seems to be a case of [`z-fighting`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting).

The idea is basically that the planes are so close to each other (and in this case occupy the same space!), that the camera that is used to draw the scene, has trouble selecting a particular plane for each of the pixels.
And so the "pattern" is just random glitches, and it changes when you move, because the computation for selecting which plane is "in front" changes for each angle.

You can read in a lot more detail [here](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Depth-testing).

Now, the pattern does remind me of "noise patterns", which you might be interested in. There's a lot of ressources for that, a good place to start could be [the book of shaders](https://thebookofshaders.com/11/).

Comment: Your comment has helped me tremendously--especially the link to The book of Shaders. Also, the information on z-fighting is super interesting! Funny that I'm actually trying to use z-fighting--and it seems to basically be a phenomenon that most are trying to avoid. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help! Don't forget to mark the answer as answered ;)